# Unable to verify the first certificate Next.js

Tags: npm, next.js

I am trying to build a new application.

It accesses one API to get some data over HTTPS.

```js
Status2.getInitialProps = async () => {
    console.info('ENTERRRRRRRR')
    const res = await fetch('https://test.com/api/v1/messages', {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ffhdfksdfsfsflksfgjflkjW50aXNocjEiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDc1ODIzODQsImF1ZCI6InJlY3J1aXRpbmdhcHAtMTAwMC5kZXZlbG9wLnVtYW50aXMuY29tIiwiaXNzIjoicmVjcnVpdGluZ2FwcC0xMDAwLmRldmVsb3AudW1hbnRpcy5jb20ifQ.0jqPutPOM5UC_HNbTxRiKZd7xVc3T5Mn3SjD8NfpEGE',
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'
            }
        }
    )
}
```

When the browser tries to access this API then it gives me the following error:

```
Server Error
FetchError: request to https://test.com/api/v1/messages failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
C
```

To solve this issue I followed [this](https://jackfisher.tech/blogs/next-js-cannot-verify-first-certificate/) but when tried it, it gave me another error:

```
'NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1):

create a `next.config.js` file if you not already have one in your project and add the following to your webpack config:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.node = {
      fs: "empty",
    };

    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    const env = Object.keys(process.env).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc[`process.env.${curr}`] = JSON.stringify(process.env[curr]);
      return acc;
    }, {});

    config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));

    return config;
  },
};
```

Do not use it like this in production. It should only be used in a dev environment.

Comment: bad for production

Comment: so what is the point of posting a solution that is not viable?

Answer (score 0):

The `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` solution is a no-go as it is against the main purpose of having a trusted connection between your front-end and API. We run into this error message recently with a NextJS as the front-end, ExpressJS as the back-end, and Nginx as the webserver.

If you or your team are on implementing the API, I would suggest looking into your webserver config and how you are handling the path of the certificates as the problem might be related to a misconfiguration of the intermediate certificate. Combining the certificate + intermediate certificate like so did the trick for us:

```
# make command
cat {certificate file} {intermediate certificate file} > {new file}
 
# config file /etc/nginx/conf.d/xxx.conf
ssl_certificate {new file};
```

Comment: What's the best way to handle this? I've server up and running with a valid SSL. Do I need one for the nextjs app as well?

Comment: Need more detail but you need a SSL for the nextjs app too

Comment: It seemed Ike the issue was with the api server as I didn't load full chain certificate.

Comment: Yes this is what I explained in my answer above. Glad you fixed it